# Изменить стиль для элемента внтури другого элементв в зависимости от содержания родителя

Tags: css

Можно ли каким-то образом на чистом CSS в [данной структуре](http://jsfiddle.net/DUM3a/) применить различные стили для пунктов 1 и 2. Не добавляя ничего к html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
li:nth-child(1) { color: red; }
```

[nth-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child)

Comment: это знаю. мне нужно было вопрос по другому задать... Можно ли как-нибудь задать разные стили для ссылки внутри li, один селектор для элемента a после которого идет еще один список, а другой селектор для a который сам в элемента списка.

Comment: [+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) и [~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) ? вы лучше пример разметок покажите

Comment: Вот То-то И Оно...(

Answer (score 0):

http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child